# Eclipse treat a directory as a subproject

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I imported a maven project which had several sub projects into eclipse using maven plugin for eclipse.

Later I wanted to add another sub project to this imported project. What I did was creating a new maven project through eclipse in the default eclipse workspace and moving the created project to the desired location of the original project.

My problem is, even though eclipse treats previous sub projects as projects, newly added project is just shown as a folder, not a sub project. So I cannot add any classes to newly added sub project through eclipse.

Here is my project structure.

[image]

It can be seen that even though some folders are shown in blue and some in yellow. The yellow ones are the ones that are not treated as projects.

Can someone help me to make eclipse identify these projects as projects.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using ?

Comment: Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the pom of the new project this way :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.firm.ex</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
```

You have to edit the parent pom this way :

```
<modules>
    ...
    <module>new_project_name</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: No, it depends on your project's architecture.

Comment: I already have set parent in the child project pom and child module is also added to the parent pom. Only thing that was missing was <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>. I added that too and restarted eclipse but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: The folder's name of your new project is the same which is defined as module's name in the parent's pom ? Maybe you could add parent's pom and new project's pom on your post in order to help.